# loading configuration settings from a database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently writing a MVVMC application in C# (utilising Entity Framework).

What is the correct (best practice) way for loading and storing configuration values?

First of all, there is the question of how to store the configuration settings... would the best way to have the table designed like this: tblConfig(configid, configref, configval) or like this:  tblConfig(configid,option1,option2,option3)  - replacing option1 etc, with meaningful names (e.g. logoimage)

Next, there is how to retreive/store the settings in the app; My idea was to store the configuration in a table in the database, and then create a static class - something like this:

```
public static class ConfigClass
{

    public static ConfigClass()
    {
        //load values from database
        ContextClass SiteContext = new ContextClass();

        logoImage = SiteContext.ConfigSettings.ToList().Find(c => c.configreference == "logoimage").configvalue;
        admintoauthoriseaccounts = Convert.ToBoolean(SiteContext.ConfigSettings.ToList().Find(c => c.configreference == "logoimage").configvalue);
        defaultaccountrole = Convert.ToInt32(SiteContext.ConfigSettings.ToList().Find(c => c.configreference == "logoimage").configvalue);

    }

    public static string logoImage = "";
    public static bool admintoauthoriseaccounts = true;
    public static Int32 defaultaccountrole = 1;

}
```

Class for the ConfigSetting DbSet Repository:

```
public class ConfigSetting
{
    public string configreference { get; set; }
    public string configvalue { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a good idea? Or should I forget the static class and just read settings directly out of the the DbSet repository?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to be able to change these setting for all users?  Do you want save the settings for each user?  This is a pretty vague description of the actual requirement.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The configuration settings are site-wide, and only one set of configuration values is allowed. I would like the site administrators to be able to change them.

Comment: When you say site wide, is that web-site or app-site wide?  If a website, changing the web.config will cause the website to restart (people may loose information), etc, etc with concerns if it's not.

Comment: web-site wide. e.g. the admins can set an option to make sure that new user accounts must be authorised first, or that new user accounts are automatically activated. But as they can be changed; I'd rather it was done through the GUI, that way I can restrict the values they enter - and ensure all config references exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most common practice is to store configuration --including the string to connect to that database-- in app.config (or web.config) for the project.  Any settings you store in the database would only add the value to, i guess, allow user modification.

If that's your goal:

1. Store user customization settings in db
2. Store application config in app.config/web.config

Otherwise:

1. Store both in app.config.
2. Serve to the rest of your layers via class, static class, singleton pattern, what have you.

Regardless of that choice:

1. Best if you do not use static class to hit the database over and over again for settings.  This will cause performance degradation.
2. Branding like a logoimage doesn't sound like something that needs to change often, or per user, and wouldn't really be worth storing in a database.

Comment: Agreed.  Yea for straight up configuration, I'd just use web.config or app.config.  If you do store config in the database, you'll probably want to implement a cache to avoid unnecessary round-trips to your database every time you need to look up a config entry.

Comment: The configuration is for site-wide settings which can be change by the administrators. I'm not too concerned about the db design - and I can certainly cache data... my main question is really about how to structure my classes to retrieve and store the settings in the application.